# Modifying the numerical values with awk in a file , following a matching pattern only

Tags: awk

I need to multiply the numerical values with a constant say 0.9 for numbers following a pattern  "-period".  Only the numbers after the pattern "-period" need to be multiplied but not for any other numbers, as there will be many numerical values in the file.
Please provide correct `awk` command options to modify the values in the file.

```
awk -F, '{$3=$3*0.9;print}' OFS=, inputfile.txt
```

is not useful as these numbers are not in a single column.

---

Contents of the file :

```
clock -period 5.00 -name clk1 
clock -name txclk2 -period 10.00 
clock -period 7.00 -name clk3 
input_delay -clock clk1 4.0
```

After modification it has to be:

```
clock -period 4.50 -name clk1 
clock -name txclk2 -period 9.00
clock -period 6.30 -name clk3 
input_delay -clock clk1 4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a simpler way to do this in awk than to iterate over the fields:

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++){if($i == "-period") $(i+1) *= 0.9}} 1' inputfile.txt 
clock -period 4.5 -name clk1
clock -name txclk2 -period 9
clock -period 6.3 -name clk3
input_delay -clock clk1 4.0
```

If you want the specific floating point format, then

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++){if($i == "-period") $(i+1) = sprintf("%.2f",0.9*$(i+1))}} 1' inputfile.txt 
clock -period 4.50 -name clk1
clock -name txclk2 -period 9.00
clock -period 6.30 -name clk3
input_delay -clock clk1 4.0
```

Note: I omitted `-F,` and `OFS=","` since your files as shown are whitespace delimited.